# How can I specify the exact number of digits that an user have to insert into an input field?

Tags: html, validation, attributes

I am pretty new in HTML and I have the following problem. Into a page I have an input tag like this:

```
<input id="codiceFiscaleEnte" class="form-control" name="numeroProtocollo" type="number" th:value="*{codiceFiscaleEnte}" required="required"></input>
```

and I have to do some validation on it.

So I know that the `required="required"` attribute means that the user have to insert a value for this field and that the `type="number"` specify that this value have to represent a number.

Can I specify in some way that this number has to be composed by exactly 11 digits? How can I do it using HTML attributes?

Comment: Use `min`, `max` and `step`. Or do you mean you want to allow `00000000001` but not `1`?

Comment: @Oriol no have to be an 11 digits integer number: something like: 12345678901

Comment: If you are only interested in the string representation and not in the numerical value, a text input makes more sense than a number one. And allows you to use `pattern` attribute.

Comment: @Oriol I know but the problem is that the input have to be composed by only numeric digits and not alphabetic  character

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use pattern:

```
<input type="text" name="numeroProtocollo" required pattern="[0-9]{11}">
```

It allows only numbers with a minimum and maximum length of 11

**Test it:**

https://jsfiddle.net/oegjdszx/1/

Comment: And what exactly specify the name attribute?

Comment: Oh, you can specify as you want, the only addition that I tell you is the `pattern` attribute

Comment: `pattern` attribute is ignored for number inputs.

Comment: Yeah, it should be `type="text"`. Sorry for the forgetfulness

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude yes but in this way the user can also insert alphabet character and I want restrict the input to only numeric digits

Comment: @AndreaNobili the pattern disallows to submit this input with non-numeric characters

Answer (score 2):

Use the `pattern` like this

```
<input pattern="[0-9]{5}">
```

Where 5 is the number of digits that you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="number" min="10000000000" max="99999999999" required>
```

`min` and `max` attributes specify the smallest and largest valid values. An 11 digit number is a number between 10^10 and (10^11 - 1), so set min and max to those values